# Do transformation of series is needed when using the code auto.arima() in R?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

So, I am doing forecasting using auto.arima. Now I am confused, if the time series need to undergo transformation into a stationary series before apply the auto.arima code?

The point forecast does have big difference but the prediction interval vary a lot.

I tried to compare the forecasted result from both series which are the original and also the one undergone transformation. I compared it by transforming the result inversely, etc I use cumsum() with the first data added back into the series for series undergone differencing.